# Bluetooth audio sink

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I have a Belkin Music Receiver that acts as an audio sink. It works great with my Android but I'd also like to play through my PC.

The device has paired and shows in my devices list but not in my playback options. The only service available is "Audio Sink" (which is checked). Is there a way to enable this as a playback device?

Comment: Check your bluetooth stack. It needs to support such feature. Also in the playback devices make sure you enables "show disabled devices".

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that windows 7 doesn't come with ad2p installed by default, you have to download the latest drivers from the manufactures.

Answer (score 1):

For me on Windows 7 Enterprise, I can right-click on the Bluetooth device in *Devices and Printers* and select *Services*

[image: Devices and Printers]

Then establish the *Listening to Music* connection, which should instruct Windows to use the A2DP profile instead of the HFP protocol.

[image: Bluetooth Services]